# How to create TextInputs in one row? (React Native)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, mobile-development

I'm trying to create 3 TextInputs in one row, but when I write flexDirection: 'row'  it doesn't work (I don't see any text inputs on device).

```
var SampleApp = React.createClass({
render: function() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.textInputWrapper}>
      <TextInput style={styles.textInput}
      placeholder='Month'
      placeholderTextColor="#d3d3d3"
      />
    </View>
    <View style={styles.textInputWrapper}>
      <TextInput style={styles.textInput}
      placeholder='Day'
      placeholderTextColor="#d3d3d3"
      />
    </View>
    <View style={styles.textInputWrapper}>
      <TextInput style={styles.textInput}
      placeholder='Year'
      placeholderTextColor="#d3d3d3"
      />
    </View>
  </View>
  );
  }
 });

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
 flex: 1,
 flexDirection: 'row'
}
});
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code here, instead of posting a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add styles for each component. Hope that help.

```
 var styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row'
 },
 textInputWrapper: {
     flex:1,
     height: 50,
     borderColor:'red',
     borderWidth: 2,
 },
 textInput:{
  flex:1,
 }
```

});